# What is the benefits of Creating menu for web application based on database?

Tags: html, css, database, web-applications, dynamically-generated

In my new job I saw that some web application before me created fully base on database. For example, All of the menu, sidebar, footer created programmatically from database. I never do this, and can't understand why they need it.
And my question is 'What is the benefits of Creating menu based on database?'

Comment: Well, probably because its dynamic, if you want to change something you don't have to access the code everytime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been doing that too, simply because of a few reason.

1. Makes it easier to add or remove some menu's in production environment (for example, when something goes wrong and you want to restrict access to that menu while you fix it).
2. Easier to maintain user privileges on menus.

Comment: Can you  give example for second reason? I understand such, some user can't see some menu items but some can  and this functionality created base on database? but, How?

Comment: Of course, for example, in the project that i'm handling right now, there are 4 tables that handles this, which is users, groups, menu, and group_menu

the users in the users tables would belong to a group via a foreign key on the users table, and this would connect the users to the group_menu table which list all of the menu which the group / user can access. Oh, and in the menu table it would be good if you also put a visibility column, since there are some menu that you can access but wouldn't want to show in the sidebar / menubar (i.e. edit user/ edit post)

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. Menu/data coming from database gives flexibility and make the website more dynamic and also easier maintenance.

Dynamic menus usually occurs on CMS or other platform/framework. For example, wordpress, magento and others programmatically creates their menus based on user modification.